# Subgraph count from a large graph (undirected) in a efficient way. How to increase performace of the R code? (Rcpp, doParallel)

Tags: r, performance, foreach, rcpp, doparallel

I am working with a very large graph (The number of vertices in the graph is 1000+, which means I working with a (1000+ x 1000+) adjacency matrix). My laptop has an 8-core CPU and 8 gigs of RAM (MacAir M1). Recently I tried to write a performance-efficient code in R. For that I used to write code in `RCPP` and for the simulation (since my original graph model is random) purpose I used the `doParallel` packages. As an example suppose we want to count the number of wedges in the graph for that I write the following code.

```
src2 <- {"#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
double wedge_cnt_cpp(NumericMatrix x){
  
  R_xlen_t  n = x.nrow();
  double temp = 0;
  
  for(R_xlen_t i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(R_xlen_t j=0; j<n; j++){
      for(R_xlen_t k=0; k<n; k++)
      temp = temp + x(i,j)*x(j,k);
    }
  }
    return temp;
}"} # wedge count function
sourceCpp(code = src2)
```

If I write this code in the base R, the performance is horrible. I am using an Erdös-Rényi model as an input in the above function. Also, I generate this adjacency matrix of the ER model using `RCPP` code.

```
src1 <- {"#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix ER_AdjMatGEN_cpp(int N, double p){
  NumericMatrix temp(N,N);
  for(int i=0; i< N; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < i; j++){
        temp(i,j) = R::rbinom(1,p);
        temp(j,i) = temp(i,j);
    }
  }
  return temp;
}"}
```

Now we want to study the asymptotic distribution of the wedge count statistic of the ER model for that we need to simulate the model. For this, I use the `doParallel` and `iteration` package.

```
Niter <- 10000
wedgeCnt_result1 <- foreach(icount(Niter),
                           v = iter(function() ER_AdjMatGEN_cpp(N, p)),
                           .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
                             wedge_cnt_cpp(v)
                           }
```

But my Rstudio crashes sometimes. with this much iteration. If we set `Niter = 10, N = 1000`
then

```
Unit: seconds
                                                                                                                                              expr
 wedgeCnt_result1 <- foreach(icount(Niter), v = iter(function() ER_AdjMatGEN_cpp(N,      p)), .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {     wedge_cnt_cpp(v) }
      min       lq    mean   median      uq      max neval
 4.831462 4.887098 5.05464 5.017306 5.18402 5.604898   100
```

I want to increase the performance of the codes (I also want to increase N). Any suggestion is helpful for me.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code review site. If you want to increase performance the usual recommendation is to time and / or profile so that you can identify where your code is slow.  And then consider improving those parts.